# Changing error colors when executing sql scripts in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

When executing sql in a visual studio sql server project, all of the output comes out in black text. This makes it difficult to quickly spot errors in the output.

Does anyone know of a way to change the color? I tried looking around in Fonts and Colors but I didn't see any settings for the sql output text.